# Java Servlets and Raspberry Pi IO

Tags: gpio, web-server, java, pi4j

I'm trying to learn how to write simple servlets to use with a Raspberry Pi. I want to control the board I/O via web.I'm using the Pi4J library which is a wrapper for the WiringPi C library.It works when I use it to blink a led locally so I assume that I'm doing something wrong coding my servlet.

This is the code I wrote:

```
package com.luca.servlet;

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;

public class MyServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

  private GpioController gpio=GpioFactory.getInstance();
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput redLed=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_23,PinState.LOW);
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput greenLed=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_22,PinState.LOW);
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput blueLed=gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_21,PinState.LOW);
  private GpioPinDigitalOutput[] pins=new GpioPinDigitalOutput[]{redLed,greenLed,blueLed};

  @Override
  public void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.io.PrintWriter print=response.getWriter();
    print.write("<body>"+ 
                   "<p> Choose a color! </p>"+
                   "<form action=\"first\" method=\"POST\">"+
                   "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"red\"/>"+
                   "</form>"+
                   "<form action=\"first\" method=\"POST\">"+
                   "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"green\"/>"+
                   "</form>"+
                   "<form action=\"first\" method=\"POST\">"+
                   "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"blue\"/>"+         
                   "</form>"+
                 "</body>"); 
  }

  public void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.io.PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    String act=request.getParameter("button"); 
    switch(act) {
      case "red":
        togglePin();
        redLed.high();
        pw.write("<p>the led is red!</p>");
        break;
      case "green":
        togglePin();
        greenLed.high();
        pw.write("<p>the led is green</p>");
        break;
      case "blue":
        togglePin();
        blueLed.high();
        pw.write("<p>the led is blue!</p>");
        break;
    }
  }

  private void togglePin() {
    for (GpioPinDigitalOutput pin : pins) 
      if (pin.isHigh()) pin.toggle();
  }
```

it compiles fine and I manually deploy it inside tomcat,with the deployment descriptor and all. But when I connect it says to me that the resource is unavailable. If I remove the GPIO related code it works fine.

Comment: Is it a permissions problem?  wiringPi requires root privileges to access the GPIO.  Does your applet have root privileges?

Comment: It is a permission problem as @joan indicated. The applet runs in the context of the webserver and has (thus) no root privileges.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas I start tomcat as sudo ./startup.sh

Comment: @Luca I assumed that you were using raspbian tomcat packages.
Note that it is incredibly dangerous to run a webserver as root. One security problem in either tomcat or your code and the intruder has root privileges on your system.

Comment: I have a software package which I think does what you are trying to achieve - as a former engineer, it might suit your needs - see http://grapl.16mb.com

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out what the problem was! I forgot to add the Pi4J libraries (the jars) in the lib subfolder of my web application. That was stupid :D .
Thanks anyway!